# Is there a simpler way to get to a member of a class wrapped in a smart pointer?

Tags: c++, c++11

Apologies for the cryptic title. Suppose this definition:

```
struct TestNode {
    using CostType = double;
};
```

I would like to be able to define a class template like this:

```
template <typename NodeP,
          typename MyPolicy = /* CostType of the node type corresponding to NodeP */ >
struct TT {
};
```

In the above definition, `NodeP` can be either a simple **or a smart pointer** to a class that defines `CostType`, such as `TestNode`. The problem: how can one specify a default value for the `MyPolicy` template parameter to be the `CostType` of the node type corresponding to `NodeP`?

Here  is my solution so far:

```
// like std::remove_pointer, but works with smart pointers as well
template <typename PT> struct my_remove_pointer {
    using type = typename
        std::remove_reference< decltype( *((PT)nullptr) ) >::type;
};

struct TestNode {
    using CostType = double;
};

template <typename NodeP,
          typename MyPolicy = typename my_remove_pointer<NodeP>::type::CostType>
struct TT {
};
```

Is there a simpler approach to this problem? In particular, am I missing a standard library facility that could make the solution simpler?

Comment: `((PT)nullptr)` may be replaced by `std::declval<PT>()`.

Comment: and you use using alias: `template <typename PT> using my_remove_poiner_t = typename std::remove_reference<decltype(*std::declval<PT>())>::type;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a helper class in the standard library called [`pointer_traits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/pointer_traits). It looks like it's exactly what you want.

[run online](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/8AhqMeZsM9kqs29T)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <typeinfo>

struct TestNode {
    using CostType = double;
};

template <typename NodeP,
          typename MyPolicy = typename std::pointer_traits<NodeP>::element_type::CostType>
struct TT {
    typedef MyPolicy xxx;
};

int main () {
    TT<TestNode*>::xxx a = 2.8;
    TT<std::unique_ptr<TestNode>>::xxx b = 3.14;
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << b << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With some usings I may be a little more readable

```
template<typename T>
using remove_pointer_t = typename my_remove_pointer<T>::type;

template<typename T>
using cost_type_t = typename remove_pointer_t<T>::CostType;
```

Now in your code

```
template <typename NodeP,
          typename MyPolicy = cost_type_t<NodeP>>
struct TT {
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Since a smart pointer supports dereferencing and `.get()`, we can write a type trait using `void_t` to get the underlying type:

```
template <typename... >
using void_t = void;

// base case: not any kind of pointer
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct underlying_type {
    using type = T;
};

// raw pointer
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct underlying_type<T*, void> {
    using type = T;
};

// smart pointer
template <typename T>
struct underlying_type<T, void_t<
                decltype(*std::declval<T>()),
                decltype(std::declval<T>().get())
                >>
{
    using type = std::remove_reference_t<
                     decltype(*std::declval<T>())
                 >;
};

template <typename T>
using underlying_type_t = typename underlying_type<T>::type;
```

If you *don't* need to support non-pointers (I'm not sure), then you can simply do:

```
template <typename T>
using underlying_type_t = std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*std::declval<T>())>;
```

Either way, once you have the alias:

```
template <typename NodeP,
          typename MyPolicy = underlying_type_t<NodeP>::Cost>
struct TT { ... };
```